# .exe file is not being created in windows for C by cmd by gcc compiler

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cmd

i am also worried about how to make u guys understand about my problem and share my experience. i am learning C.in previous, i used the Code-blocks IDE to compile and run C code.i learned that as a beginner it would better to use cmd to compile and run code than IDE. i am using windows 8. Before i was not use to with cmd, i also learned  that to be a advance user and good programer i should know the use of cmd well. 
After setting the environment variable started to compile c code by cmd by the following command

gcc -o "executable file name"               "C source code file name"

it craete a .exe file. but no .o file. when i worked with IDE, also a .o file was found with .exe

1. what is the possible reason for it?

after compiling the code, i ran it by calling "executable file name".
and when checked the directory, then a .exe file was found.
but now the problem is, recently i am compiling and running code, i found that there is no .exe file created, but a file has created with  unknown extension"**POINTERWHILE File (.pointerWhile)**"(copied from file properties). this unknown extension file is only runing by the cmd. it may be the one part of my source code file name. the code has given below and the name of source code.

Name of source code: Example184.1.pointerWhile

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
 {
  char *p = "stop";
  char str[80];
   do
    {
     printf("Enter a String: ");
     gets(str);
    }
  while(strcmp(p,str));
 }
```

this program will take input until, "stop" entered.

this kind of things happened for several other files.then i copy them, to an another folder and compile and run but the same result.

i complied and run the same code form same folder and other folder by codeblocks, the result is same. the file is only running when it is in IDE.

then make an another file with other name in same directory and other, but the same code. then it is creating .exe file.

2.what may the cause for creating .exe file?

Comment: Try asking smaller, simpler questions. I have hardly any idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: If you give GCC a number of `.c` files, it will compile them and link them into an executable, and will not save any intermediate `.o` files. If you want this behavior, you need to pass `-c` to GCC, telling it to only compile, and not link.

Comment: then how to make .exe file from .o file? what is the use of a only .o file @JonathonReinhart

Comment: Stack overflow is not meant to teach every detail about how compilation goes. You need to find a good book, resource, or instructor.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great effort from you in learning the cmd along with C!

However, I think you're confusing the extension (name) of the file, and its contents. When you tell gcc to generate an executable file, you might want to give it a .exe extension, just like you said, assuming your source is called "myprog.c":

```
gcc -o myprog.exe myprog.c
```

This should always generate a myprog.exe file. But nothing prevents you from calling it like this:
    gcc -o myprog.myFancyExtension myprog.c

You should still be able to run the program via the cmd (I didn't test that on windows though). Note that on other systems, like Linux, executable files usually have no extension at all.

Also, you're talking about how your IDE generates a myprog.o object file along with the myprog.exe executable file. To do this, your IDE is calling the compiler (gcc) twice: once to generate the .o file, and another time to generate the .exe file. There is no way to generate both files in one run of the compiler. The advantage of learning the cmd is that you will learn what your IDE is actually doing for you without telling you. The drawback is that you have to actually learn it ;)

Usually, people do not like to use gcc by hand, because as your projects grow, they will use different files and it becomes tedious to recompile them all manually. To overcome this, you will want to use a build tool, such as Make. I'm not familiar with development under Windows, so I can't recommend any specific tool. The point of those tools is that when your project has multiple source files, you only have to call the builder once, like this for Make:

```
make
```

instead of manually calling:

```
gcc -c myFeature1.c
gcc -c myOtherFeature.c
gcc -c myYetAnotherFeature.c
gcc -c myMain.c
gcc -o myMain.exe MyMain.o myFeature1.o myOtherFeature.o myYetAnotherFeature.o
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The motivation of doing work with cmd I got from Linux. I was tried  to learn Linux but I found some problems. I was unable install software in Linux without internet mean the Ubuntu software center. I searched in internet but unable to understand them and use the search results. As a result I was totally internet dependent. I tried to duel boot my pc Linux alongside windows but to do this accidently all of my hard drive was formatted, I lost my data. Though somehow I have recovered all of them. Then I thought I should use the resource that all ready in my hand means the windows cmd.

Comment: If u have any resource for learning Linux as beginner please don’t forget to share. @KrahnacK

Comment: Yes, nowadays people most likely use the Internet to install software, in Linux, Windows, and OSX (instead of CDs or other sources). In my opinion, Ubuntu has made a lot of efforts to be user-friendly, so I'd recommend it for beginners. If you have any problem with it, you can always post on the Ubuntu forums, or on askubuntu.com.

Here's a link that may be helpful:
http://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-resources-to-get-help-with-Linux